# Azure Durable Function Activity Trigger Required?

Tags: azure-functions

I have a simple Durable Function where my goal is to perform some background work (in this case spin up an Azure Database).

I've got the following code which is working, however I'm wondering what the purpose of need the ActivityTrigger function.

If I don't include it and attempt do work in `CreateDB` itself, the Durable Function never correctly completes and remains Running.

```
public static class CreateDBFn
{
    private const string CreateDBConstant = "CreateDB";
    private const string CreateDBTaskConstant = CreateDBConstant + "Task";

    [FunctionName(CreateDBConstant + "Start")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
   [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, methods: "post", Route = CreateDBConstant + "/{Name}")] HttpRequestMessage req,
   [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClientBase starter,
   string Name,
   ILogger log)
    {
        string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(CreateDBConstant, Name);

        log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");

        var res = starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        res.Headers.RetryAfter = new RetryConditionHeaderValue(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        return res;
    }

    [FunctionName(CreateDBConstant)]
    public static async Task<bool> CreateDB([OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContextBase context)
    {
        var Name = context.GetInput<string>();

        // I'd like to just do work here
        await Task.Delay(30000);

        // Why is it required to call out to an Activity?
        var success = await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>(CreateDBTaskConstant, Name);

        return true;
    }

    [FunctionName(CreateDBTaskConstant)]
    public static async Task<bool> CreateDBTask([ActivityTrigger] string Name)
    {
        // preform work
        await Task.Delay(30000);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is discouraged to start async operations in orchestrator code, the only exception being code started by the durable orchestration context, for instance `CallActivityAsync()`. This is due to the checkpoint-replay behaviour of orchestrator functions.

Relevant excerpts from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable-functions-checkpointing-and-replay#orchestrator-code-constraints)

> Orchestrator code must never initiate any async operation except by using the DurableOrchestrationContext API. For example, no Task.Run, Task.Delay or HttpClient.SendAsync. The Durable Task Framework executes orchestrator code on a single thread and cannot interact with any other threads that could be scheduled by other async APIs.
>
> Tasks that can be safely awaited in orchestrator functions are occasionally referred to as durable tasks. These are tasks that are created and managed by the Durable Task Framework. Examples are the tasks returned by CallActivityAsync, WaitForExternalEvent, and CreateTimer.

Comment: So just to confirm this is the correct way to call the code above? I need essentially 3 methods to do an async task that can return a pending result immediately?

Comment: Yes, you would need the orchestrator client (triggered), the orchestrator function and the activity that actually performs the work. Still, I don't understand why you are using an orchestrator to perform a logic that does not strictly require orchestration. For your purpose, shouldn't it be enough to have just a single triggered function that asynchronously spins up the database?

Comment: But I’m kicking off the database creation from an asp.net endpoint. I can’t reliably run a background task or have a thread wait while the dB gets created. It could take multiple minutes for the db to create, make sense?

Comment: In my opinion my goal is to kick off a function and have it return with an endpoint where I can check progress. Only way I can do this is with the above durable function flow I think

Comment: Sure, in that case an orchestrator makes sense. Be careful, since the process might take several minutes, that if you are running your functions in a Consumption Plan, you have a default maximum execution timeout of 5 minutes (can be extended to 10), after which your activity function will be terminated.